# Laravel auth CORS issue

Tags: cordova, authentication, laravel-4, cors

I'm having the same issue with Laravel authentication and CORS as this thread:

[Auth::user() returns null with CORS requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23271609/authuser-returns-null-with-cors-requests)

Although, my files won't be hosted on the same domain as they will be used within a Cordova smartphone application. Does anyone have any ideas how to solve this, and still use Laravels standard Auth functionality?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by first adding the following headers to App::before function in routes:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Auth-Token, X-Request-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

Then I changed the driver of sessions to cookie.

And I didn't preform Auth::guest() the first thing I did in the filter, but rather checked for the token if it was accessable in the User table, then connected the User-object to the Auth-object, if Auth::user was null.