# Laravel 4 CORS installation

Tags: php, laravel-4, cors

Am tried to integrate CORS in lavaval 4. I have tried the statement

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors:0.2.1
```

Am am getting following result:

```
./composer.json has been updated
> php artisan clear-compiled
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-cors 0.2.1 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-cors[v0.2.1].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework 4.0.x-dev
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 4.0.x-dev
    - barryvdh/laravel-cors v0.2.1 requires illuminate/support ~4.1 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[4.1.x-dev, 4.2.x-dev, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.12, v4.1.13, v4.1.14, v4.1.15, v4.1.16, v4.1.17, v4.1.18, v4.1.19, v4.1.2, v4.1.20, v4.1.21, v4.1.22, v4.1.23, v4.1.24, v4.1.25, v4.1.26, v4.1.27, v4.1.28, v4.1.29, v4.1.3, v4.1.30, v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0-BETA1, v4.2.1, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
    - don't install illuminate/support 4.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 4.0.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support 4.2.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 4.0.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.1.0|don't install laravel/framework 4.0.x-dev
    ..........
    ..........
    - don't install illuminate/support v4.2.9|don't install laravel/framework 4.0.x-dev
    - Installation request for laravel/framework == 4.0.9999999.9999999-dev -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[4.0.x-dev].
```

And I couldn't able to integrate laravel CORS. What is the issue with the installation.

Comment: You may consider checking this [input](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29673946/6381711)

Answer (score 1):

The current version that your laravel is (4.0.x-dev) is not supported.

I'm fairly sure you're running a **very** old version that might not even be secure. You should update Laravel to the newest version (newest Laravel 4 if you prefer it to 5) and then install all the stuff you want.